# How to create a type with expanded argument list of template<typename... Args> function?

Tags: c++, types, function-pointers, variadic-functions, c++20

In general, I have a poor idea of how to create such a type:

```cpp
template<typename... Args>
using TWrapper = void *(*)(void *target, Args... func_args);
```

I understand why this is throwing errors, but I don't know what to do about it ...

I am developing a class with content something like this:

```cpp
template<typename TFunc> //TFunc is a type of user's function
class CallManager {
    TFunc user_function = nullptr;
    void* inner_state; //For example

    template<typename... Args>
    using TWrapper = void *(CallManager::*)(void *const target, Args... func_args);

    TWrapper wrapper_from_another_instance = nullptr; //What do I need to specify in the template arguments if I don't know them?

    template <typename... Args> //I need to create a type for this function
    void* WrapUserFunction(void *const target, Args&&... func_args) {
        user_function(std::forward<Args>(func_args)...);
    }

    void setTargetExecutor(TWrapper wrapper) {
        wrapper_from_another_instance = wrapper;
    }
public:
    void setFunction(TFunc func) {
        user_function = func;
    }

    template <typename... Args>
    void makeCall(Args&&... func_args) {
        wrapper_from_another_instance(inner_state, std::forward<Args>(func_args)...);
    }

    void bindManager(const CallManager &next) { //Upd 1
        setTargetExecutor(next.WrapUserFunction);
    }
};
```

Using the example of the above class, it is possible to notice that I need an "extended" type in order to create a variable-pointer to a function for it, and then call it.

My class accepts a custom function type, but I don't know how many arguments there are and what type they are. Is it possible to somehow extract the list of arguments?

**How can I create a type for a function starting with "*template<typename... Args>*"?**

**How can I supplement the user's type with my own argument to save the result in variable for call?**

*UPD 1: example of usage*

```cpp
using myfunc = void(*)(char x, char y);

void myFunc(char x, char y) {
}

void main() {
    CallManager<myfunc> cmgr1;
    cmgr1.setFunction(myFunc);

    CallManager<myfunc> cmgr2;
    cmgr2.bindManager(cmgr1);

    cmgr2.makeCall(10, 15);
}
```

Comment: Could you please add also a sample usage of this class?

Comment: @KamilCuk The point is that I am writing a wrapper around the C interface. The above part is an excerpt from a class that deals with creating and processing calls. In C-lib, everything about custom types is handled by the user (the C-api uses `void *` all over the place), but in C++ this is bad style.
It may not be so easy to write meaningful usage for this example, but I'll try.

Comment: This seems like a very strange interface. Why exactly two `CallManager` instances to call the function?

Comment: @Caleth I just gave an example. The real class implements other functionality: there managers are used in different program modules, the first manager calls the second, and so on, each has hooks that decide whether to continue the call or interrupt it. This class is quite large, so I created an example purely for the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you limit you class to take function pointer, you might do:

```
template<typename TFunc> //TFunc is a type of user's function
class CallManager;

template<typename R, typename... Args>
class CallManager<R (*)(Args...)>
{
    using TFunc = R (*)(Args...);
    using TWrapper = void *(CallManager::*)(void *const, Args...);
// ...
};
```

If you need to support more callable type, I suggest to create a "`function_traits`" in the same principe ([template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization)) as helper.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3852a2e53a122fb)/[Demo2](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e589bf5f02ef808)

Comment: Is it possible to reduce the number of template parameters to one (e.g. function class)?
I suppose this can be done with `std::function`, for example, but how do I get the types then?

Comment: And why does the template initialize when the class is declared?
This line: `class CallManager<R (*)(Args...)>`

Comment: There is only **one** template parameter. `CallManager<void (*)(int, char)>` (mostly as `std::function<void(int, char)>`, you can even drop the pointer from declaration).

Comment: `class CallManager<R (*)(Args...)>` is for [template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization).

Comment: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e589bf5f02ef808)s added.

Comment: I noticed that the example used `using TWrapper = void(*)(const CallManager*, Args...);`, but for member functions, in theory, `using TWrapper = void(CallManager::* )(const CallManager*, Args...);`. But the second option does not work for me with the error `Error C2064 term does not evaluate to a function taking 3 arguments`. The first option works, but why is it so? The first option should refer to a regular C function, but not a member function, as far as I understand. After all, for a member function, a pointer to a function is not enough, it also needs a context.

Comment: @AlexA.: Your sample has several error ignoring the `Args...` main issue. First Demo (creaetd before your example usage) uses method pointer, instance to apply was missing; I use `this`. In second, it seems that `inner_state` is the instance, so either should be in parameter or regular function, or should not be parameter of method (I select the former).

Comment: Yes, I didn’t pay attention to the word “static”, which eliminates the need for context. My main code had an error in the syntax of calling a member function, as I was testing on global functions. Its OK now.